# What happens when writing to a socket from different threads at the same time?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, tcp, ffmpeg

I have two threads, each with a buffer with some data. I have a function that writes to a TCP socket. (I use ffmpeg for it.)  How will the data packets arrive at the server — in some crazy mixed up way, or in some other order, or will the OS (Windows, in my case) make one thread wait until the other has finished?

Comment: What is your sockets implementation, and what API(s) are you using to do the writes?

Comment: Satan himself will come forth from the nearest empty network portal.

Comment: @Noah: so what happens when two different threads make Satan himself come forth from the nearest empty network portal at the same time? What about in the case where the threads are running on different cores of a CPU which is *exactly* equidistant between two network portals, so that one is closer to one core and the other closer to the other? Enquiring minds want to know.

Comment: I guess that will cause demons to come out of Satan's nose. Haven't tried it, though, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends entirely upon which implementation of "sockets" you are using. If your implementation is synchronized, you'll get the first thread's data, followed by the second thread's data (The second thread will block while the first sends). If your implementation is not synchronized, you'll get gibberish.

Comment: @Kabumbus - then why is the q tagged C++? How are you doing the writes?

Comment: I believe there's no such a thing as "unsynchronized" sockets implementation. At least when you talk about TCP sockets. Take into account that "writing" to the socket is a complex operation. Among other things it modifies the TCP control block state machine.

Comment: I mean - every operation on the socket is *atomic*. Of course if thread writes the data via several calls to `send` (or similar) - there may be the salad.

Comment: @valdo: Every operation is atomic if and only if your implementation is synchronized. If the implementation is not synchronized you will get garbaage.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: My point is: if your stream socket implementation is not synchronized - you may get much worse consequences, maybe even system crash. Hence - I believe threre's no such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

mmm, well, you have to synchronize them, to avoid unexpected results.

Comment: This is complete speculation without more info on the code in question

Comment: nope, I said that, because, Kabumbus didn't show any code, and We don't know what kind of implementation is he using. So, for me there is not enough information to do some code.

Comment: well, that's a little unfair - it's certainly fairly *typical* behavior.

Comment: @Eamon - if the sockets function in use is threadsafe, then it's overkill to add your own synchronization. This answer makes a definitive statement that "you have to do your own locking".  At least the other says "it depends".

Comment: If there is not enough information for you to answer the post a comment on the question. Answering a question you don't understand or don't have enough information on will lead to answers that have no relevancy.